How to save fine tuning LLM model?
I am doing fine-tuning of a model and then I want to save this model to convert it to the GGUF format to use in Ollama. However, when converting to the GGUF format, I get the following error: ValueError: Can not map tensor 'model.layers.0.mlp.down_proj.weight.absmax'.
I'm not sure if I am saving it correctly. Can anyone help?
import transformers
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig
import torch
from langchain.llms import HuggingFacePipeline
from langchain_community.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
import csv
import sys
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
print("Device:", device)
if device == 'cuda':
    print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))

origin_model_path = "IlyaGusev/saiga_llama3_8b"
model_path = "IlyaGusev/saiga_llama3_8b"
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path, trust_remote_code=True,
                                             quantization_config=bnb_config,
                                             device_map="auto")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(origin_model_path)
text_generation_pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    task="text-generation",
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    repetition_penalty=1.1,
    return_full_text=False,
    max_new_tokens=2000,
    temperature=0.5,
    do_sample=True,
)
mistral_llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=text_generation_pipeline)

loader = CSVLoader(file_path='data/data_issues.csv')
data = loader.load()

print(data[:3])

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
chunked_docs = text_splitter.split_documents(data)

embeddings_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name='sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2')
db = FAISS.from_documents(chunked_docs, embeddings_model)

retriever = db.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={'k': 16})

qa_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(mistral_llm, retriever, return_source_documents=True)

query = "Example answer"
chat_history = []

response = qa_chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})

fine_tuned_model_path = "./fine_tuned_model"
model.save_pretrained(fine_tuned_model_path)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(fine_tuned_model_path)


Please add your call for the conversion to GGUF and its output.
